# smarty engine in drupal

Tags: drupal, smarty

Preferred Download Links for smarty engine in drupal are dead:
https://www.drupal.org/project/smarty

Can anyone give me how to get smarty engine work in drupal ?

Comment: You should stick with standard solutions or you'll end up with unique problems and nobody will be able to help you. If you are "forced" to use D7 or older version just stick with PHP template but if you have ability to choose go to D8 and twig.

Answer (score 0):

While there is a [Smarty](https://www.drupal.org/project/smarty) module, it has no release for Drupal 7 and I doubt there will be one.

For Drupal 4 and 5, there were various efforts made to use different template engines. However, nearly all contributed themes for Drupal 6 and 7 are done in PHPTemplate and almost all documentation and available support are for PHPTemplate.

Even if you're already familiar with Smarty, if you're going to use Drupal seriously for more than one project I would highly recommend learning PHPTemplate. At this point, you would have to do work to integrate Smarty into Drupal 7 on your own, which would almost certainly be harder than just learning PHPTemplate. Going with Smarty will also limit your support options.

Note: D8 uses [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) template